# Default controller and default action in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I have a website developed in MVC 5, I'm using **route attributes** for routing.
I've set **the** **default controller** and **the** **default action** for each controller using the following code

```
 public class CompanyController : MainController
 {
  [Route("~/", Name = "default")]
  [Route("Company/Index")]
  public ActionResult Index(string filter = null)
   {
     //My code here
   }

  [Route("Company/Edit")]
  public ActionResult Edit(int id)
  {
    //My code here
  }
 }
```

I've another controller with a default action :

```
[RoutePrefix("Analyst")]
[Route("{action=Index}")]
  public class AnalystController : MainController
 {
    [Route("Analyst/Index")]
    public ActionResult Index(string filter = null)
    {
      //My code here
    }

   [Route("Analyst/Edit")]
   public ActionResult Edit(int id)
   {
    //My code here
   }
 }
```

The default controller worked perfectly, but when I navigate to the analyst controller without specifying the name of the action I get the following error:

```
Multiple controller types were found that match the URL. This can happen if attribute routes on multiple controllers match the requested URL.

The request has found the following matching controller types: 
SurveyWebsite.Controllers.AnalystController
SurveyWebsite.Controllers.CompanyController
```

How can I correct navigate to http://localhost:61534/analyst and reach the default action ( index) ? The action also should remain accessible by http://localhost:61534/analyst/Index
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give an empty string as the route value for index action so that it works for Analyst, which is your controller route prefix. You can decorate with a second `Route` attribute for it to work with "`Analyst/Index`" url where you will pass "`Index`" to it.

```
[RoutePrefix("Analyst")]
public class AnalystController : MainController
{
    [Route("")]
    [Route("Index")]
    public ActionResult Index(string filter = null)
    {
      //My code here
    }

   [Route("Edit/{id}")]
   public ActionResult Edit(int id)
   {
    //My code here
   }
}
```

This will work for both `/Analyst` and `/Analyst/Index`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the action won't be accessible by http://localhost:61534/analyst/Index

Comment: @BilelChaouadi Missed the that part in your question :( I updated my answer to work with both the urls.